# How can I ask for input in a GUI based input text area in Swift for MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm using xcode version 13.3.1 to learn swift for macOS. I wanted to know how I can have an input box show up after a button is pressed and use that input in my program. So far I have a function that is connected to a button.

Comment: SwiftUI or AppKit?

Answer (score 0):

Learning Swift and learning how to create apps with an event-driven UI are two different, non-trivial tasks. Then there's learning the Appkit for developing apps for Mac OS.

You might want to start with building a command-line tool. That would let you concentrate on first learning Swift, and then you could move on to learning AppKit and how to build event-driven GUI apps.

As to your specific question. It's been a while since I've done MacOS development, so my answer may not be exactly correct. You'll probably have a view controller that has an IBAction attached to your button. You'll probably define your UI in a storyboard.

Then you'll probably want to create a text field (NSTextField or NSTextView). Add that to your storyboard and get your window's layout the way you want it (using auto-layout constraints) Attach your text field/text view to an IBOutlet in your view controller. Set the text field's hidden property to true so it starts out hidden. Also implement the appropriate NSTextField/NSTextView delegate methods in your view controller, then connect the text field/view's delegate link to the view controller.

In your button's IBAction method, set the text field's hidden property to false to show it.

Then you'll need to figure out how to respond to user input. Do you want to respond as the user types, wait until they press enter, have a button for the user to tap, or something else?